# 12 labeled balls into 4 unlabeled boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I'm wondering how many combinations of 12 labeled balls in 4 unlabeled buckets can be made, distribution must be even, so 3 balls per bucket.

My sense is the answer is effectively c(11,2)=55.  I deduce this by dropping the first ball, and then calculating how many other combinations can be made with that ball.  But, I am wondering if there is another way to think about it.

Comment: Are you asking for the total number of partitions of a 12-element set into 4 sets of size 3? Or the maximum size of a collection of such configurations with the property that no 3-element set appears twice?

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways of partitioning the $12$ balls: $${12 \choose 3} \times {12-3 \choose 3} \times {12-6 \choose 3}$$

Since boxes are unlabeled, you can permute and the boxes and hence a given partition will repeat $4!$ times in the unlabeled order.

So number of unlabeled partitions are:
$${12 \choose 3} \times {12-3 \choose 3} \times {12-6 \choose 3} \times \frac{1}{4!}$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the division by 4! unneeded? Since the boxes are unlabeled, I feel like this question just reduces to "How many ways can you partition twelve labeled balls into four equal groups of three"

Comment: But you can permute the sets in a partition  and the questions stills counts it as a single partition because boxes are unlabeled ?

Comment: Does this result in the order with a box mattering?  Would ABC and CBA in a box be counted twice?

Comment: @XStanton 4! Is needed as for 12C3 that 3 balls picked can be put in any one of 4 unlabelled box, it has 4 choices, and then 9C3, 3choices, …

Comment: order of balls with a box should not matter neither the ordering of sets in the partition.

Answer (score -2):

Since the four boxes are unlabeled, this question reduces to "How many ways can you separate twelve labeled balls into four equal groups.

We first choose 3 balls for the first group, leaving nine balls. There are $12\choose 3$ ways to choose these first three balls. Now from the remaining nine we need to choose three more for the second group. There are $9\choose 3$ ways to choose these next three balls for the second group. Since we need to take into account each of the $12 \choose 3$ cases that are possible in the first choice of three for the first group, we need to multiply $12\choose 3$ and $9\choose 3$, giving us a total so far of $12\choose 3$$9\choose 3$. For the third group, we have six balls to choose from and we need to choose three of the six once again. There are $6\choose 3$ ways to do that. Once again, we need to take into account all the different possibilities for the first two groups, giving us our new total of $12\choose 3$$9\choose 3$$6\choose 3$. This leaves us with three balls left. But these three balls will constitue the fourth group no matter what balls our first three groups are made from. Therefore, there are $12\choose 3$$9\choose 3$$6\choose 3$ different ways to separate twelve labeled balls into four unlabeled boxes.

Comment: Choose $1, 2, 3$.  Then choose $4, 5, 6$.  Then choose $7, 8, 9$.  Or instead, choose $4, 5, 6$.  Then choose $1, 2, 3$.  Then choose $7, 8, 9$.  You have enumerated this combination of choices twice, but it’s the same partition.  That’s why your answer is wrong.